# Which work by Aristotle features the most references to Euclidean geometry?

Tags: aristotle

I have dipped into the *Metaphysics* pretty extensively, and I know that he uses a number of fascinating methods for decomposing arguments in that book. No wonder St. Thomas Aquinas read it while he was imprisoned. The book is a cerebral *tour de force*.

One of the above mentioned methods for decomposing arguments is geometrical. He draws analogies between the way three-dimensional figures are drawn and the way propositions about Plato's forms constructed, in order to shed a dubious light on the latter. I have to say that while I love his thinking style in that book, he's preaching to the choir really. I have never really liked Plato's forms, so I tend to tune out there and tune back in when he brings up the likes of Anaxagoras and Democritus.

So I'd like to know where else I can read that kind of 'shapely' argumentation, particularly where (else) Aristotle makes the most references to Euclidean geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Henry Mendell discusses *Greek mathematics in Aristotle's Works* in SEP:

> Here are twenty-five of his favorite propositions (the list is not
>   exhaustive). Where a proposition occurs in Euclid's Elements, the
>   number is given, * indicates that we can reconstruct from what
>   Aristotle says a proof different from that found in Euclid). Where the
>   attribution is in doubt, I cite the scholar who endorses it. In many
>   cases, the theorem is inferred from the context.
>
> ```
> 1. In a given circle equal chords form equal angles with the circumference 
>     of the circle (Prior Analytics i.24; not at all Euclidean in conception)
> 2. The angles at the base of an isosceles triangle are equal (Prior 
>     Analytics i.24; Eucl. i.5*).
> 3. The angles about a point are two right angles (Metaphysics ix 9; Eucl. 
>     follows from i def. 10).
> 4. If two straight-lines are parallel and a straight-line intersects them, 
>    the interior angle is equal to the exterior angle (Prior Analytics ii.17; 
>    Eucl. i 29, cf. 28).
> 5. If two straight-lines are parallel and a straight-line intersects them,the 
>    alternate angles are equal (possibly, but not likely Prior
>    Analytics ii.17 (Heiberg), although the theorem is about parallel
>    lines and uses (7); Eucl. i 29*).
> 6. If a straight-line intersects two straight-lines and makes interior or 
>     exterior angles equal to two right angles on the same side
>    with each, then the lines are parallel (possibly Posterior Analytics
>    i.5 (Blancanus, Heath), but it is possibly the weaker theorem that
>    each angle formed by the intersecting line is right, rather than their
>    sum equals two right angles); Eucl. i 28*)
> 7. The internal angles of a triangle are equal to two right angles (frequent, 
>    but cf. Prior Analytics i.35, Metaphysics ix.9; Eucl.
>    corollary to i.32*)
> 8. The angle in a semicircle is a right angle (Posterior Analytics i.1, ii.11, 
>     Metaphysics ix.9; Eucl. iii.31*)
> 9. In a right triangle the squares on the legs are equal to the square on the 
>    hypotenuse (De incessu animalium 9 (Heath); Eucl. i.47).
> 10. To find the mean proportion of two lines (De anima ii.2, Metaphysics 
>    iii.2; Eucl. vi.13, cf. ii.14)
> ```

Complete list is [here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-mathematics/supplement4.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Aquinas's works, including his commentaries on Aristotle, contain many references to mathematics, all of which are documented [here (& ff.)](http://archive.org/stream/FilosofiaDeLosMatematicasEnSantoTomas#page/n75/mode/1up).